# Pronunciation of "substituent": [sʌbˈstɪtʃuənt] or [səbˈstɪtʃəwənt]

Tags: pronunciation

Why is "substituent" transcribed in different ways?

Generally, it is transcribed as /sʌbˈstɪtʃuənt/ ([As Wiktionary does](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substituent)) But the phonetic transcription given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substituent) is /səbˈstɪtʃəwənt/.

Which is 'correct'? /sʌbˈstɪtʃuənt/ or /səbˈstɪtʃəwənt/?

On [*How to Pronounce*](https://www.howtopronounce.com/substituent), it sounds like there are two variants; should there be a /w/?

Comment: The full OED gives **/səbˈstɪtjʊənt/** and **/səbˈstɪtʃʊənt/** as BrE pronunciations, and **/səbˈstɪtʃ(əw)ənt/** as AmE (in all cases the first vowel is reduced to a schwa). Which apart from that initial syllable is exactly the same phonetic transcription as that for ***constituent***, so why ask about this obscure domain-specific borrowing from German?

Comment: Because pronunciation varies? I doubt that there's any one word that is pronounced identically by everyone.

Comment: Exactly. And how does one tell whether a sequence is [ʃuə] or [ʃəwə]? Have you got your recordings and wave forms?

Comment: @Heartspring: Thank you for editing my question to make it better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sorry for putting the question not clearly. I meant to ask about the end part /...tʃəwənt/, the "w" sound, not about the first vowel.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for your comment. I didn't record myself. I listened to recordings provided on the websites. Could you please elaborate on what you meant by the "wave forms", please?

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you. So, are both correct? Do you know which is preferable?

Comment: Short answer: I don't. Long answer: Of course there's no "right way" to say a word; there's only what people normally do, and that can vary by region or culture, to the point that your listener might misunderstand or mock you if it doesn't fit their experience. Some words have variant pronunciations that are often censured or mocked, like "nukyular" or "astericks." To the best of my knowledge none of the versions of "substituent" discussed here have any such perception—in fact, I'm seeing only very slight differences, to the point that people who say one would hardly notice the other.

Comment: Obviously the first vowel is different. I was asking why you chose to ask about the rest of the pronunciation for such an obscure word, when *exactly* the same 3 variants exist for ***constituent*** as for ***substituent***. Why didn't you ask about ***constituent*** instead? At least that would be a word most people would recognise!

Comment: @amai - no problem

Comment: @AndyBonner I see your point. Thank you ^^.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, sorry, I'm not a native speaker. I didn't know that "substituent" is obscure, compared with "constituent". Thank you for your information. It is a term in organic chemistry though, to refer to an atom or group of atoms substituted in place of a hydrogen atom on the parent chain of a hydrocarbon (by [ByYu's](https://byjus.com/question-answer/what-is-substituent-group-plz-help-to-clarify-the-topic/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster transcribes as /əw/ what the vast majority of other lexicographers transcribe as /u/ or /əʊ/ (or /oʊ/ or /o/) in an unstressed position before another vowel. Jack Windsor Lewis [wrote](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive18.html#blog174):

> In the new 1961 edition of Webster’s *Third New International Dictionary* the leading American pronunciation lexicographer of his day, Edward Artin, included an innovatory style of transcription for words like *obstruent* and *strenuous* etc. He explained in that work (at p. 37a) that he favoured transcriptions like \ˈstrenyəwəs\ because he felt ...“a very strong conviction that ... such pairs as” *silhouette/Scylla wet* were “exact rhymes” and that this clearly indicated in consequence that his new transcriptions of such items were more satisfactory representations of the normal pronunciations of such words.
>
> In writing *silhouette* in a phonemic transcription one’s choice is essentially between /sɪl.u.`ɛt/ and /sɪl.ə.`wɛt/. Most lexicographers have preferred to use the former type no [doubt] because it correlates more satisfyingly with the orthography. Yet it can hardly be denied that it tends to suggest a slightly slower and/or more deliberate enunciation than the word ordinarily receives and that the latter version, despite its containing a suggestion of a schwa which can’t be straightforwardly correlated with the word’s orthographical form, satisfies the criterion of sounding not unduly deliberate and producing an effect that probably anyone would regard as normal. Of course it [would] be possible ideally for lexicographers to show both versions of such words [e.g.] *strenuous* as /`strenjuəs/ and /`strenjəwəs/ but it’s simpler and space-saving to choose one alternative with the understanding that the other is not being simply rejected.

Comment: Thank you. It's informative and very interesting to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here.

The vowel of the first syllable:

- When a syllable comes at the start of a word and ends in a consonant, it  usually isn't pronounced with /ə/. Instead, it is pronounced with what is called an "unreduced" vowel. An example of this is the word *trombone.* Prefixed words are an exception to this rule (see Greg Lee's answer here: [Can foreign words be reduced into English morphemes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270600/can-foreign-words-be-reduced-into-english-morphemes/272706#272706)), but some of them can optionally be pronounced with an unreduced vowel. So for some speakers, /sʌb/ and /səb/ are variant pronunciation options.
- Separately from that, some speakers don't distinguish the sounds /ʌ/ and /ə/. In this case, there would be no meaningful difference between /sʌb/ and /səb/.

The last two syllables:

- When the vowel sound /u/ comes before another vowel, we may hear what is called a "linking semivowel" after it, meaning, it sounds kind of like /uw/ or, if unstressed, it might sound like /əw/ or /ʊw/. There is no contrast in this context between a pronunciation with or without a "w" sound. Since it is not contrastive in terms of meaning, it makes sense not to include it in a phonemic transcription (which is what slashes technically are used for), so I would prefer the transcription /uənt/. That does not mean that you need to avoid using a /w/ sound here: it's fine as long as you don't overdo it by making it sound as strong as the /w/ found at the start of a syllable in words like "went". The phonetician John Wells writes

> Syllable-final sonorants are shorter, more lightly pronounced, than the longer, more deliberate, syllable-initial ones.

([linking semivowels (ii), John Wells’s phonetic blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/linking-semivowels-ii.html)):

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer thoroughly addressed my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are different pronunciations for the same word in American and British English dictionaries. Meriam Webster is a American dictionary and Wiktionary is mostly a British one. That might be the reason of the variation. An example from **Britannica** is given below:
"The most obvious difference is the way the letter r is pronounced. In British English, when r comes after a vowel in the same syllable (as in car, hard, or market), the r is not pronounced. In American English the r is pronounced."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I really don't see how last sentence of your answer is relevant, given that there are no 'r's in *substituent*.

Comment: Except in New England, where we pahk the cah in Hahvahd Yahd.

Comment: @PeterShor that was just an example to show how pronunciations can be different in AmE and BrE